# SharePoint: Excluding specific folders from search

Tags: sharepoint

I've been searching around, trying to figure this out.

I have a document library, which looks like this: `site.sharepoint.com/Storage/Shared Documents/Products/`

Inside `/Products/`, there are many different folders, like `/Products/Product1/`
, and inside those again, I have two other folders called `/Archive/` and `/Original/`. Keep in mind that every `/Product/` have these two folders.

What I want to do, is to exclude `/Archive/` and `/Original/` and their contents from search. Since every folder has these two subfolders, I can't exclude a specific path, and this makes it more complicated.

Any help would be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the provided structure

```
Shared Documents (library)
    |
    --Products (folder)
           |
           -- FileA.docx
           |  
           -- Product1 (folder)
               |
               --Archive (folder)
               |    |
               |    --File1_2018.docx
               |     
               --Original (folder)
                   |
                   --File1.docx
```

the following query

```
IsDocument: 1 AND Path:https://site.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Products/Product*/Original/*.*
```

will return the results:

```
File1.docx
```

where

`IsDocument: 1` sub query tells to return files/pages only

and `{weburl}/Shared Documents/Products/Product*/Original/*.*` expression tells to include results from path which corresponds to sub folder `Original`

**Update**

For that matter you could utilize `UrlDepth` property which limits the folder depth.

For the provided above example, the following query

```
IsDocument: 1 AND Path:https://site.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/ AND UrlDepth=3
```

will return the following results

```
FileA.docx
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! The thing is, I don't want the search to show any files from either `Original` or `Archive`. Inside `/Product1/` there will be files that needs to be included in the search, but not its subfolders.

Comment: @TobiasKKS, the answer has been updated, I believe you are looking for UrlDepth property

Comment: @TobiasKKS, any luck with the provided solution?

Comment: @Vladim Gremyachev Thank you so much for your response. I will be trying your solution next week when I have time. I'll make sure to let you know :) Another quick question though, do you know how to include custom filetypes in search results?

Comment: Using UrlDepth makes the search result return no results at all. Any idea?

Comment: Never mind, I used an invalid urldepth. Thank you so much, you saved me from alot of hassle!